# Where can I best exchange cash from USD to euro?

Tags: money, international-travel, tips-and-tricks, exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best method for exchanging dollars for Euros?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-is-the-best-method-for-exchanging-dollars-for-euros)

I have sold some equipment and the buyer paid cash which I now need to change from US dollars to Euros. I'm wondering whether I will get a better rate in different countries. My options are USA (San Francisco, New York), UK (London) or Germany (Berlin). Does it make a difference where I am or is it just a matter of shopping around for best rates on the day?
This is a cash transaction — please do not suggest ATM's, credit cards etc.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [exchanging dollars to euros](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110/101) question