# Benefits (or drawbacks) of ordering Euros from AAA (American Automobile Association) online

Tags: europe, schengen, money

I am due to visit Europe on a Schengen visa for about a week in August. I was looking at various ways to get some petty cash (in Euros from USD) before flying.

Most of my expenditure will be paid for by an academic organization but I would still like some cash in my pocket. In addition, I have nice travel credit cards with no foreign transaction fees with me to use in an emergency.

Now, I have [read a similar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-is-the-best-method-for-exchanging-dollars-for-euros) question on what some of the best practices are, in terms of exchanging USD to Euros. That question also touches on the fact that AAA type associations can also be used to exchange currency but does not explain the advantages or disadvantages of that approach vis-a-vis other approaches.

Since, I am an [AAA member](http://westerncentralny.aaa.com/?zip=14850&devicecd=PC), I was wondering if any other AAA members or otherwise have any experience in [ordering Euros from AAA online](http://westerncentralny.aaa.com/discounts/financial-services?zip=14850&devicecd=PC&referer=www.aaa.com) and if they could elaborate on the advantages and disadvantages of ordering from the AAA online versus other methods.

My ultimate objective is, as a student, to optimize my meagre finances when traveling in Europe.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question fits the stack exchange format (yet). Could you maybe be a bit more specific on what aspect of the money ordering process you want people to comment? Right now it is too broad to answered usefully.

Comment: thanks. made several edits to the question. is this more suitable?

Comment: It does not seem possible to find the cost of ordering Euro from AAA unless you log in as an AAA member. Why don't you do that and compare with the suggestions made in the answers to the question you're linking to?

Comment: I did ! Its $10 + shipping (another $10) for the amount of euros I want to buy.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to get Euros in advance if you have a credit card with no transactions fees? Just hit an ATM once you arrive in Europe. You probably won't find a cheaper or more convenient option.