# Should I convert US dollars to euros while in USA or in Europe?

Tags: usa, europe, money, greece, san-francisco

I will eventually end up with so few US dollars when in San Francisco airport, that I won't have to declare them to customs when I arrive at Greece.

Should I convert them to Euros in SF, or in El. Venizelos airport at Athens? Or it's pretty much the same fees in both cases?

Comment: Unfortunately it's pretty much the same.

Comment: @JoeBlow would you like to post an answer with that then? :)

Comment: @gsamaras Do you know the rate at which you can sell dollars in Greece?

Comment: Sell? What to do you mean @Karlson?

Comment: Wells Fargo in San Francisco at $1.18 to 1€; Hellenic Bank at $1.13

Comment: Hellenic bank? You mean National bank of Greece? Also pleas explain, because I have no idea how all this works..I think you are suggesting go going to the bank in  Greece and give them my US dollars?

Comment: `Also pleas explain, because I have no idea how all this works. I think you are suggesting go going to the bank in Greece and give them my US dollars?`  How else do you think you can exchange dollars to euros? Of course you have to give them your dollars.

Comment: Any bank in Greece.... Alpha Bank, Eurobank Ergasias, National Bank of Greece, Piraeus Bank... will exchange dollars for euros.

Comment: How much money do you have? Under 100 bucks the difference is negligible.

Comment: I think this is covered by [What is the best method for exchanging dollars for Euros?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-is-the-best-method-for-exchanging-dollars-for-euros): that also talks about using cards, but covers cash as well. Basically, so long as you don't change at the airport, it'll be pretty much the same, make sure you change somewhere that's not a captive market

Comment: “so few”... the limit is €10000!

Comment: hi @Dorothy, unfortunately those figures mean: nothing.  The FEES added totally swamp any exchange rate differences. (Unless you're exchanging millions of dollars on the money market.)

Comment: Please don't answer the question within the comments. Comments are for clarification requests, and not answers.

Comment: This is a shopping question and I have voted to close as such, not necessarily a dupe.

Comment: @gsamaras Technical term.  When you exchange for dollars you're buying dollars.  When you exchange dollars for another currency you sell dollars.

Comment: Ah OK Karlson. So @user568458 basically what you say is not to exchange the money in the airport, and go to a bank in Greece and do the conversion.

Comment: Regarding your photo question: http://www.itagsoftware.com/

Comment: Good luck! :):)