# Where to exchange money in Wroclaw

Tags: exchange, poland, wroclaw

I'm arriving to Wroclaw airport (Ryanair) next April, where should I exchange most of my money? In the airport, in the city or in another city?

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10/101, http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1911/101.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of ATMs and Exchanges all around the city, especially in city center.

At ATM, you will get a rate controlled by bank and Exchanges have their own rates. They may be a bit less interesting at airport (I suppose), I would suggest exchanging money somewhere at market place or [Galeria Dominikanska](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Galeria%20Dominikanska,%20Plac%20%20%20Dominika%C5%84ski%203,%20Wroc%C5%82aw,%20Polen&hl=pl&ie=UTF8&sll=51.107885,17.038538&sspn=0.532859,1.18927&oq=galeria%20d&hq=Galeria%20Dominikanska,%20Plac%20%20%20Dominika%C5%84ski%203,%20Wroc%C5%82aw,%20Polen&t=m&z=15).

However, ATM seems more convenient (at least to me).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, almost wherever I go, I find it's easiest to get money out of the ATM.  (Aside from Uzbekistan, where ATM's were card-specific).  Ideally if you can before you go, arrange for a debit card or similar with zero fees for withdrawing in other countries - your bank may be able to offer you one, or you can order one online.  Some really good tips on [MoneySavingExpert](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/travel/cheap-travel-money).

Comment: I'm afraid that this kind of card doesn't exist in Spain :(

Comment: I'd be surprised, usually your bank (you have HSBC in Spain) can offer something like this.  Alternatively, some credit card companies can.  But otherwise just do what I do and rely mostly on my bankcard to draw cash out.  And I know *those* exist in Spain, because I've drawn cash out there (and had it stolen, but that's a different story)

Comment: HSBC in Spain? Let me check... yes, but only big cities has offices. I've heard that ING Direct offer a credit card that allows to get cash for free in any country, but I gone to an ING office and they were not sure about this. I'll ask again, but this is an always open question in spanish travel forums :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of the arrangements in Poland but in Ukraine the best way to get local currency would be to simply withdraw it from an ATM.  All the exchange places would give you worse rate then you would get for the electronic money transfer from bank to bank.  And from my exprience airports are the worst.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to visit [Kantor Cent](http://www.centkantor.pl) at the city center, prices very close to FOREX market, much better than bank's rates.