# What is the best money exchange place to exchange dollars to PLN in Poland

Tags: exchange, poland, wroclaw, krakow

I am looking for a place to change dollars to Polish zloty and I wonder where the best place to do such exchange is.

I am looking for exchange places in following cities (or nearby):

- Wroclaw
- Krakow
- Walbrzych

Additionally can I ever count for an exchange rate that is better then what google shows?
(06/01/12  1 U.S. dollar = 3.55219597 Polish zloty)

Does anyone knows a good `kantor` in wroclaw and what the exchange rate there is ??
What is the exchange rate at galeria dominikanska??

Comment: For Wroclaw (rules apply country-wise, though), see [http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/where-to-exchange-money-in-wroclaw/5182.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're taking cash? The best advice for this sort of thing [is to use a suitable cash card to withdraw from an ATM](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your/17#17), not to try to change cash

Comment: I did not have a bank account that operates in Poland. So i feared I would not be able to withdraw money in Poland so i just took cash.

Comment: @Xitcod13: you should have been able to get VISA or MasterCard. Even in San Diego.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I been to `kantor`s all over Wrocław and looked at the exchange rates all over the city the exchange was 3.45  at most places, where as the best exchange price was 3.497 at the Alior bank near the city center (rynek). The exchange prices change every day but I suggest checking this location before exchanging somewhere else.

Answer (score 9):

In general in Poland specialized currency exchange offices (`kantor`) are much better than banks. I would guess that in bigger cities you will get a better deal, you should shop around and compare rates in different offices (so probably Wroclaw or Krakow).

Google shows the average exchange rate at a given moment, so you are pretty much guaranteed that you will get a worse rate (because the exchange office earns on the spreads). However, the rate does change all the time, so it will be different in a few days.

Comment: As addition to what Grzenio already wrote, the best rates are in the city, not at the airport.

Comment: @mithy, indeed you are guaranteed the worst rate at the airport :)

Comment: A few days ago I saw around ~3.2/4.3 conversion rate for EUR. :D

Comment: Actually on top - Google shows the forex rate. Unless you want to translate a significant amount WITHOUT CASH INVOLVED - this is irrelevant for you. My own bank here in Poland allows me to exchange with FOREX+Fee using their broker - a lot better. But if you at any side have cash (like physical USD, not a USD account) - expect to pay for the handling. THe notion of a better price than google quotes is comically ignoring the reality of the service a Kantor provides (which includes handling the physical side, which is absent from the quoted forex rate).

Answer (score 3):

In my (recent) experience, better than change money is to find any cashier and get money from it. That's when you need cash, because almost any restaurant, hotel, shop, etc will accept paying by card, that gives even better exchange.

**Note**: My credit card is an Euro based VISA, I don't know if that's important.

Comment: In Poland money exchange offices will often give you better exchange rate than a credit card.

Comment: @Grzenio well, may be, but that's not my experience

Answer (score 3):

At many exchange shops (kantor) you even can negotiate exchange rate, if you sell or buy larger amount of dollars/euro.

Watch out for those "kantors", that are in very touristic places, like in Old Town of Kraków (Cracov). They often have *very* bad exchange rate.

The rate when selling is always lower than average and for buying is always higher. There is however no commission. If someone wants you to pay commission, find another place.

Answer (score 3):

Wroclaw:

1. Crossroad Swidnicka and Olawska street in the old town. kantor: CENT
2. Olawska street 50 m from the main square: GANT

The best way to find good echange rate is to look at the difference between the sales and buy rate. If it is higher than 7 groszy on one unit price  eg 1 Dollar look for another place.