# Withdrawing Euros from Moroccan ATMs?

Tags: money, atms, morocco, marrakech

Are there ATMs in Marrakech where I could withdraw EUR? Do these come with additional fees? Would I be better off buying the EUR in the US at a bureau de change? (New York or Chicago)

I'm planning on withdrawing MAD for most of my expenses (Is this unwise?) but there is one place I'm staying where the owner has requested I pay him in EUR.

### Related Questions

[Availability of ATMs and exchange places in Morocco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/availability-of-atms-and-exchange-places-in-morocco): Discusses general availability of ATMs in Morocco
[Should I change most of my money in my home country or in the destination country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/should-i-change-most-of-my-money-in-my-home-country-or-in-the-destination-countr): Suggests withdrawing currency from an ATM offers the best rate

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to get Euros rather than Morocco's own currency?

Comment: @Gagravarr edited question, but basically one of the places has explicitly requested payment in EUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wise to obtain MAD from an ATM after your arrive. Using your bank card at a local ATM will get the best exchange rates, minus a small fee. Some banks will refund this fee to you, so check the terms on your account. To find an ATM, check whether your card is part of the PLUS (Visa) network or the Cirrus (MasterCard) network. If it's part of either of those, you can find ATMs online:
PLUS Network: www.visa.com/atmlocator/
Cirrus Network: http://www.mastercard.us/cardholder-services/atm-locator.html

You're unlikely to find EUR ATMs in Morocco or the United States. Your best bet would be a major bank in either country (US banks will probably have a smaller spread). A bureau de change would also serve the same purpose. Be sure to compare rates before buying euros. Most will publish their rates online.