# Exchanging US dollars for Australian Dollars

Tags: money, australia, exchange

Traveling to Australia, where is best place to exchange money?  US Bank?  Airport in LAX?  SLC airport or in Australia

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your)* Also see *[Should I change most of my money in my home country or in the destination country?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/)*

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? The airport is possibly the most convenientplace, but you will most likely get the worst exchange rate there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Bank of America ATM card you can use Westpac ATMs in Australia and New Zeeland for free. There is still foreign exchange fee, but it's a lot less than any alternative.

Check with our US bank about Australian partner banks.