# Where is generally the best place to exchange currency for a trip?

Tags: international-travel, money, exchange

In general, where is the best place to exchange currency when going for a trip? Some options include:

- a bank before you leave
- some exchange service before you leave
- at the airport before you leave (doubt it)
- at the airport when you arrive (doubt it)
- at some place at your destination (sounds risky)
- using some online service (?)
- something I didn't think of?

Please also consider in your answer that I would want to exchange back any leftover currency at the end of my trip. If it matters I live in the US.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? For me, "best" is whatever requires the least planning. If I need cash, I go to an ATM when I arrive. This is also usually the cheapest option.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad since answers may vary depending on the currencies and location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I change most of my money in my home country or in the destination country?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/should-i-change-most-of-my-money-in-my-home-country-or-in-the-destination-countr)

Answer (score 1):

Mom-and-Pop money changers near a business district (compromise between security and better rates). Being in a (central) business district and an airport, AFAIK gives you the worst rates.

Banks maybe, if you are a long-time client and hold significant worth of accounts with them.