# Currency management when backpacking?

Tags: money, backpacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your)

I am going in a trip round Europe this summer (more info)
http://www.tripline.net/trip/Eurotrip_Bruce-6031502460441004AB55F3DFBEB7A2DD?n=63

I have got my budget sorted out however now I need to think about how I will transform that into currency (**Euros).**

I have been looking around the internet for what is the best way to deal with currency and have found these methods that people do so far.

- **Bulk currency exchange in home country (in a bank or post office);** this seems to be the cheapest way to get your currency with a lower percentage commission taken from your money. The only problem with this though is that I will have to carry all my cash around with me which would not be safe when backpacking.
- **Travel Credit Card**; http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/travel/cheap-travel-money As you can see from that page it gives some good advice about travelling abroad. It also mentions there are some credit cards with 0% charges when withdrawing cash abroad. The only problem I can see with this is when im in an area with no ATM or that does not accept my card.
- **Travellers Cheques**? Don't really know much about them and whether or not they are suited for backpackers?
- **Changing currency abroad**; means taking my own currency (pounds) abroad with me and changing it over in a country. It might give me a better exchange rate but it still means I need to carry my own currency which could be risky.

Was hoping people here could maybe expand on the methods I have found or tell me there own methods for dealing with currency which are suited for backpackers.

I quite like the idea of getting a bank card with 0% currency charges, does anyone have experience of doing this in a country?

Thanks

Comment: Where are the duplicates then? Nothing came up when I wrote this question