# Preparing money for a visit in Dubai

Tags: money, dubai, uae

I plan to travel to Dubai and i know that they use AED (Dirhams) as curency. I'm from France and I would like to know if it is better to go to Dubai with American dollars or euros? Where should I exchange them? in France or in Dubai?

Comment: Have you considered taking a bank/credit card with you and using an ATM? Or do you have other reasons not to want that? See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your)

Comment: "Opinion-based"!?! It's an undisputable fact that EUR is better than USD here, because it will avoid having to exchange currency twice. (Of course, ATM is best.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend withdrawing AED from an ATM in Dubai. There is likely an ATM in the airport so you can do this as soon as you land.

The ATM will charge you a flat fee for withdrawal, while money changers will charge you a percentage of what you convert.

Comment: There are indeed several atms once you've exited into the main hall, near where the taxi drivers lurk :)

Comment: There are ATMs right before immigration as well, for those that need to pay the on-arrival visa fees. You can find them near the bank counters.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to come with 100 Euros for emergency use, then withdraw cash from an ATM.  You'll get the best exchange rate this way.  Credit cards are common in Dubai and you should be able to use them pretty easily for a lot of things (and this is much safer than cash too!).

Also, you can check with your bank.  If you have an international bank like HSBC, they might have a branch or ATMs in Dubai.

There are money exchanges in Dubai (many!) but the rates are much worse than if you use an ATM or bank.

Answer (score 5):

**There are ATMs all over Dubai airport (and the UAE)**.  The rate that your bank charges you to withdraw - depending on the amount - will be less than your loss for exchanging money.

Example: if your bank charges you €2 to withdraw from a foreign ATM, and you withdraw the equivalent of €200; that is 1% loss; whereas converting to Dirhams in your airport's exchange will likely be a greater loss.

**Use the ATM's - they're safe and there are lots to choose from.**  The lowest penalty I found was ADCB, but that may have changed in the last year.

UPDATE: I think the lowest amount to withdraw from most ATMS is 100AED, which is the equivalent of €15 or 20.  So just keep that in mind - it doesn't change my recommendation, but if you just wanted 10AED or whatever, it won't be possible.