# What is typical buy/sell spread in cash exchange booths for EUR, USD in Serbia?

Tags: exchange, serbia

What spread (buy vs sell exchange rate difference, %) can be typically expected in cash currency exchange booths in Belgrad airport, Terminal 2? In rural regions of Serbia (e.g. Kopaonik)?  Interested both for EUR and USD.

(follow up from [this thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24267/serbia-which-currency-typically-has-the-smallest-spread-buy-vs-sell-in-exchan#comment40997_24270))

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I found so far.

## Belgrade Airport

1. Сash exchange machine in the airport, right at the baggage pickup area upon arrivals, as of 1 March 2014:
   **USD**: buy 80 (while official selling rate of National Bank of Serbia was 84.8722)  -- which gives *at least* spread **6.09%**, very likely more
   **EUR**: buy 110 (rate of National Bank of Serbia was 116.2834) -- which makes *at least* spread **5.71%**
2. Via [Thorn Tree fellow traveller](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2383519), these are exchange rates for the banks that have offices in the airport, as of 21 Feb 2014:

   [AlphaBank Serbia](http://www.alphabankserbia.com/dobrodosli.redp.html)
   **EUR**: 113.9363 / 117.8771 (hence spread is **3.46%**)
   **USD**: 81.7767 / 87.1835 (hence spread is **6.61%**)

   [Komercijalna banka](http://www.kombank.com/inc/kurs.asp)
   **EUR**: 114,1681 / 117,6453 (spread **3.04%**)
   **USD**: 83,2129 / 85,7473 (spread **3.04%**)

## Kopaonik

A sample rate as of 03-Mar-2014 in the downtown was:
  **USD**: 81 / 84 (spread **3.70%**), while rates at VIP system in Belgrade were 82.7 / 85.5
  **EUR**: 113 / 116 (spread **2.65%**), while rates at VIP system in Belgrade were 115 / 116.5

Comment: @MarkMayo Does it help? :-)

Comment: Well you answered your own question, so I guess it helped :) You can probably accept it too.  I've awarded the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a website that I'm referring whenever I'm about to check exchange rates for different banks (although I'm looking for average exchange rate, not for certain bank) [enter link description here](http://www.kursna-lista.com/)

As far as I know, they're using National bank of Serbia exchange rate as a reference [enter link description here](http://www.nbs.rs/internet/cirilica/index.html)

Certain banks such as Credi-Agricole and Societe Generale have a "Non-guaranteed exchange rate" which gets better conversion rates when chosen.

I put my Mastercard, choose that option and withdraw certain amount of Serbian dinars (RSD)