# Is it quite expensive to Exchange euros to pounds and vice versa at Heathrow?

Tags: london, exchange, lhr

I am planning a visit to London. I was wondering what are the optimum choices to exchange euros to pounds and pounds to euros?

Is there an extra charge, apart from the exchange rate?

Is it safe to do it in Heathrow?

For a 2 day stay, eating finger food, not drinking and not spending a lot of money(except some cheap street souvenirs) what is fair amount of money to be needed?

Comment: Hi and welcome to travel.se. You're asking many question in one post and some of them are not answerable. What is "safe" for you? Also the budget question is opinion based - one will spend 50 euros and another one 500.

Comment: [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your) will largely cover you - an overseas friendly card + ATM is likely to be better value than any currency exchange place

Comment: Don't know about Heathrow, but in Amsterdam the banks at the airport charge the same rate and fee as the offices of those same banks in the city. No reason London should be different. Safe? Can't think of a much safer place to exchange currency than the arrivals hall of a major airport. Not many other places with that much security in place :)