# Cheapest way to get money in Prague with a London bank account

Tags: money, atms, prague

I am travelling to Prague from London for a couple of days.
I do have some questions.

1. Should I exchange my money here in the UK first? Or should I just use my credit card at the ATMs there in Prague? (the second will be more expensive right?)
2. If I exchange my money here in the UK where is the best place to go?

Comment: This mostly depends on your local bank, making the question pretty difficult for us to answer. I don't know about UK banks, but some banks in the US have no foreign transaction withdraw fees, and reimburse all ATM fees, which would make using an ATM card from such a bank a clear winner.

Comment: See [this answer on the "When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?" question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your/17#17) - it has you fully covered