# Going to US, information on forex to be carried

Tags: usa, exchange

I would be flying to US (California) for employment next week. To survive for the first month, until I get my first paycheck I'll be carrying some US Dollars from India. I have decided to carry around US$600 with me. However, I need some help on whether it's a good idea to carry the entire amount in currency notes or divide it among currency notes and traveler's checks. I am also thinking about carrying a forex card maybe, as an option. Either way if I lose any of them, I'll be losing the amount, isn't it? Or does it work in a different way?

Comment: Many questions here can answer yours: [question 1](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your), [question 2](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your)

Comment: Traveler's checks can be replaced if they are lost, but I am not sure if they are widely accepted in the US these days.  I am not sure what a forex card is but it sounds like it is some sort of prepaid credit card - if it is Visa or Mastercard compatible, you'll be able to use it to buy things and withdraw cash, but there may be fees.  Whether it can be replaced if lost is a question you'll have to ask the issuing bank.

Comment: I would forget about traveller's cheques as they are too old fashioned.  prepaid cards are fine - but you do suffer fees.  Will you be in SF?  It's not especially dangerous.  Just personally I'd just keep the 600 clams in my pocket, and just don't make a fuss about it.  Don't forget, if you do have a "normal" bankcard (of some type) with your bank at home, you can simply use that to withdraw money from any ATM anywhere. that's usually the cheapest way too.