# Best way to obtain Canadian Dollars traveling from the US

Tags: canada, money, los-angeles, weekends

I'm travelling from Los Angeles to Canada. I need a few hundred Canadian dollars in cash. What is the best option (minimum rates + processing fees)? As I see it I have 3 options:

1) Get cash from the **LA area**. Sounds like the best option but I have a time constraint: it is hard to find a place that does this on **Sunday**. Any suggestions? Does Western Union do this?

2) Get cash at LAX or the Canadian **airport** during travel

3) Use the ATMs of Bank of America's affiliates in **Canada** (Scotiabank ABMs)

I have a Bank of America account. I would prefer avoiding option 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Using an ATM is normally the cheapest way to go, unless you have an account with stunningly bad overseas fees/rates. Any reason why you don't therefore want to just use your ATM card abroad?

Comment: Just security. The airport (YUL) I alight at seems to have no Scotiabank ATM. I'd like to have cash on hand in the transit from the airport to my place of stay.

Comment: Exchange just the bare minimum of cash for a 15 minute cab ride at the bad rates you'll find, and ask the taxi to swing by a Scotiabank ATM on the way to where you're staying?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your)

Comment: @Mark: This one is more specific and includes time constraint. Thanks, though.

Comment: I have always used ScotiaBank to get Canadian money.   It's usually better to get as much as you can in one trip to save on fees, especially in a country that is mostly free of violent crime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I work in a bank and from my experience the cheapest way to get cash:

1. ATM (Debit Card) in Canada (best possible rate, unless you are dealing in large amounts).
2. Change USD to CAD in Los Angeles.
3. Change USD to CAD in LAX. (airport rates are higher)
4. Change USD to CAD in Montreal.
5. Change USD to CAD in YUL. (again, airport rates).
6. ATM (Credit Card) in Canada. (credit card network surcharge + withdrawal fees make this the most expensive)