# Best place to buy Swiss Francs using US dollar

Tags: usa, money, switzerland, exchange

I will be going to Switzerland soon, and will need Swiss Francs before I leave.  Where can I bet the best rate to buy Swiss Francs?  I live in SF Bay Area.

Comment: The conventional wisdom is not to exchange currency at all, but to [use ATM machines](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10).

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the linked question is about safety.

Comment: @JoErNanO The linked question has lots of information on this exact problem, any why changing cash will normally give a worse rate than the alternatives

Comment: @gagravarr True but just because answers are the same doesn't mean the questions are duplicates.

Comment: @JoErNanO We have lots of people coming on here asking about the best place to change one set of physical money for another sort. Outside of restricted currencies and currencies with "blue" rates, the answer is almost always "you don't want to be doing that in the first place, see this for what you need to do instead". If we refused to close a USD-CHF question as a duplicate of a USD-EUR one because the currencies didn't match, but the advice was identical (don't!), we'd have millions of questions...

Comment: @Gagravarr Come to the chat. ;)