# What's the best way to buy Swedish Kronas from Brazil

Tags: money, exchange, brazil, sweden

I'm brazilian and I'll be living abroad at Sweden for two years, starting in August. I need to exchange a reasonable amount of Reais (R$, brazilian currency) to Swedish Kronas.

The options I see so far are:

- Exchange R$ for swedish kronas at a currency exchange house and take the money with me (unsafe)
- Visa Travel Money: Exchange R$ for dollars and put them in a Visa Travel Money. When I arrive at sweden, I exchange them to Swedish Kronas

Are there any other options? What is the best (cost-efficient, safe) way of buying Swedish Kronas while still in Brazil?

Comment: Wire the money to a (reputable!) online currency broker, and deposit it in a Swedish bank account which you open on arrival?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get enough money to cover your immediate needs, see [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your/7437).  TL;DR: Get a debit card with low fees, withdraw from ATM.

For larger amounts, open a local Swedish bank account, then use an online currency broker: you transfer R$ to their Brazilian account, they convert the money and deposit into your Swedish account.  The fees on this will be *much* lower than going through a bank or anything involving cash.

Comment: Can I open a Swedish bank account from Brazil?

Comment: If the answer is too long, tell me and I'll post another question

Comment: You don't need to, all you need is a Brazilian bank that lets you do local transfers online.

Comment: And where will I transfer the money to?

Comment: 1) You transfer from your Brazilian account to the broker's Brazilian account. 2) Broker transfers money to their Swedish affiliate. 3) Swedish affiliate transfers money to your new, shiny Swedish bank account, which you opened after you arrived.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that. I didn't want to wait until I get to Sweden to open the account and transfer the money. Something could go wrong in the account creation and I'd be stuck there with no money

Comment: Once you've got your *personnummer*, which you'll need to do *anything* in Sweden, opening a bank acct is straightforward.  This may take a few weeks though, and is probaby worth asking separately on Expatriates.SE!

Comment: Opening local bank accounts is an expat issue, not a tourist issue.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right.