# Where can I purchase UAE Dirham with good deal in Dubai?

Tags: exchange, dubai

Although Travelex and other foreign exchanges are located in Dubai airport, the exchange rate and fee is quite high.

Where can I purchase UAE Dirham in Dubai with good deal?

Comment: What currency do you want to exchange for AED?

Comment: And why haven't you followed our [standard advice on getting foreign currency](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your/17#17)?