# which is the safest way to carry money on a trip to the United States?

Tags: usa

which is the safest way to carry money on a trip to the United States?

- I need to pay taxes (to travel country)? where and when I pay ?
- I can use this money in neighboring countries (eg: canada) ?
- I need to have some document ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your)

Comment: That answer is mostly for Americans traveling to Europe, not much about people traveling to the USA and Canade.

Answer (score 1):

Carrying cash is a bad idea. You might be victim of [asset forfeiture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States) or run into money laundering laws. *In theory,* you can carry cash as long as it is properly declared.

Comment: Carrying large amounts of cash is not a great idea for a number of reasons. Carrying up to a few hundred USD at a time is perfectly reasonable and common for tourists and locals alike. If the OP literally followed your advice, he'd have no cash at all. While it's possible to visit many parts of the US and rely entirely on credit cards, having at least some cash for small purchases, the occasional cash only shop, taxis with "broken" CC machines, emergencies, etc... is common.