# Where in Hyderabad can I exchange Azerbaijani manats?

Tags: india, money, exchange, azerbaijan, hyderabad

I need to exchange Azerbaijani manats in Hyderabad, India. Where can I do it?

Comment: Why not take dollars to Azerbaijan or use your card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your)

Comment: Suresh, are you trying to change **rupees into manats *before*** travelling from India to Azerbaijan, or trying to change **manats into rupees *after*** travelling from Azerbaijan to India? (or maybe do you just have a bunch of Manats somehow and you need to change them while in Hyderabad?)

Answer (score 2):

You can't - you'll have to exchange them for euros or dollars in India and then change them in Azerbaijan or Georgia

Comment: It's also possible that OP has Azerbaijani currency which they wish to exchange for Indian rupees.