# Are there ATMs at Robert L. Bradshaw International Airport in St Kitts?

Tags: airports, money, caribbean, skb

Heading to [Robert L. Bradshaw International Airport in St Kitts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Bradshaw_International_Airport) fairly soon, I've just discovered I don't have as much USD cash as I thought I had left from my last trip west... We've been told we'll need either USD or EC$ for the taxi to where we're staying, and the estimate is more than I've got left!

I've tried looking on [the St Kitts Tourism page for the airport](http://www.stkittstourism.kn/explore-st-kitts-getting-here-airport.php), the [wikipedia page for the airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Bradshaw_International_Airport), and [WikiVoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Saint_Kitts), but I can't seem to find out if there are ATMs at the airport or not?

(If not, I'll need to change some money to USD before we go, but the exchange rate is [likely to be worse here than using an ATM there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your/17#17), so I'd like to avoid that if possible!)

Comment: According to this, there aren't any: http://www.ihatetaxis.com/airport/SKB-Robert-L-Bradshaw-Airport/Robert-L-Bradshaw-Airport-atm-bank-machines-foreign-currency-exchange#atm

Comment: @MichaelC. At first glance the website looks like auto-generated search engine bait. Is it a reliable source?

Comment: I don't know if it's reliable or not. It was just what showed up when I googled the question. OP could just call the airport.

Comment: Just tried the [Visa ATM searcher pointed at the town nearest the airport](http://www.visa.com/atmlocator/index.jsp#(page:results,params:(query:%2717.29055415241972,-62.739810518066406%27))), that suggests no Visa ATMs there, assuming their database is complete...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [St. Kitts-Nevis-Anguilla National Bank Ltd](http://www.sknanb.com/atm.html) indicates that it has an ATM located at RLB International Airport.

Comment: And they do! Outside by the entrance to departures, from arrivals turn right outside customs and go along past the snack bar. Didn't have any money in it yesterday though....