# What is the best way to pay in Canada as a European?

Tags: canada, toronto

I will travel to *Toronto* and *Waterloo* and I would like to know what is the best way of paying.

- Can I use my MasterCard credit-card?
- Is it better to change my EUR to CAD there?

Comment: Changing money is never a good idea, it's more expensive than just pulling money out of an ATM.

Comment: to those answering, do Euro cards  work with "tap" payment? (Very useful for small amounts, typically between four or five dollars and $100)

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10/when-traveling-to-a-country-with-a-different-currency-how-should-you-take-your/35?s=5|0.8321#35

Comment: @JanDoggen This depends both on the fees involved with withdrawing money and the currencies. While the exchange rate in withdrawing money is better most of the time, if you have an exchange bureau with a good rate, withdrawing money only makes sense if you want to withdraw several hundreds of euros/dollars/...

Comment: @martin.koeberl I misread the question as *getting money to pay with*. In hindsight, the OP seems to want to pay with plastic directly.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience in Toronto, nearly everywhere took credit / debit cards (Visa, MasterCard, American Express...). Change some small amount of money before travelling (or pull it out of an ATM when there) just in case, and go forth with your MasterCard.