# TD or CIBC to exchange CAD for Pesos

Tags: money, exchange

My girlfriend and I are travelling to Mexico soon, and I was wondering which bank to exchange our Canadian Money for Mexican Pesos. I bank with CIBC and she banks with TD. We're thinking about exchanging $200 CAD each. But were not sure which one would give us more money or if theyre both the same.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Welcome to the site! This is something you can easily find out from each of the banks. Going to the branch would work surely, but a lot of banks allow you to order foreign currency online through your online banking portal.

Comment: TD publishes their [exchange rates](https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/solutions/currency-exchange/#/fxcalculator#Tab_NonCash) online for anyone to see, but CIBC does not; you would need to log in to your account to see them. There's unlikely to be any significant difference; the big difference would be if you used your debit cards in Mexico. CIBC wins in that case.

Comment: Voting to close as a "shopping" question. Answers to this kind of thing are likely to go out of date very quickly, and few people in the future will be interested in this specific pair of banks and specific pair of currencies. The general advice at [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10/11491) may be useful.